# Default joomla form styles

Tags: html, css, forms, joomla, content-management-system

http://askanier.square7.ch/der-askanier/login-frontend?view=registration

As you can see, there are no styles applied at all to the form. The site uses a template I created. This may be a dumb question, but how can I reset the default styles from joomla for only the forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla has no "default" style for forms.

It does however have a default template (Protostar) which uses Bootstrap styling for everything. What you could do is create a [template override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for the Registration view, copy over the form styling from the Protostar CSS file you your own template CSS file.

Out of all honesty though, I would simply style them yourself as Bootstrap forms would not blend in well on a design like yours.

### Update

I appears your HTML markup for the form already uses Bootstrap, so simply import the CSS code